# Store data as Text File from HTML

Tags: javascript

I want store data from an html page to a text file using javascript on Client Side. Any method is there?

Comment: Just found it today: http://www.downloadify.info/ (it uses a combination of JS and Flash)

Comment: Good question .. very informative .. keep it up ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store as file in Client Side with javascript, most of the browsers not allowed you to do that.

Comment: Yes you can! The user must explicitly agree but that is all.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](http://ajaxian.com/archives/dojostorage-offline-access-and-permanent-client-side-storage) how to do it (with user intervention)

Also try [these](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557) [APIs](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/10/21/store-large-data-client-side-with-amass/#).

You cannot do that automatically without user intervention (Thank God!)

Comment: Great links, Crimson.  I'm going to give PersistJS a try for my application.

Answer (score 2):

You can't work with the filesystem with JavaScript. Flash can work with the filesystem, so a combination of JavaScript and Flash (such as [Downloadify](http://downloadify.info/)) will work.